# SQL Server getting newest entry returns wrong results. What am I missing?

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange behaviour with a SQL Server query/function.

I have a table with 3 columns (actually there are more columns, but these 3 are relevant for this task). The columns are `FileId`, `UserId` and `TimeCreated`. It is possible, that one user can create the same `FileId` multiple times, and I want to know, which was the newest created file.

I am doing it with this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE TimeCreated IN (SELECT MAX(TimeCreated) 
                      FROM table 
                      GROUP BY FileId, UserId)
```

In my opinion this should be correct, but for some groups, it returns multiple rows, even if the `TimeCreated` is different.

Here is one result as an example:

```
TimeCreated              | UserId | FileId
------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-18 00:00:00.000  | UserA  | FileA
2016-01-18 06:00:00:000  | UserA  | FileA
```

But it should only return the row with '2016-01-18 06:00:00:000' as `TimeCreated` value.

I don't understand what is going wrong, because there are a lot more entries, which have UserA (as UserId) AND FileA (as FileId) but different TimeCreated values but it only returns this two rows (so in some way, it is quite working) and like I said, for some groups it is ok, but sometimes it returns two rows with the same UserId and FileId but different TimeCreated values. And when this happens it's always two rows and not more.

The `TimeCreated` is a `DateTimeOffset(7)`, `UserId` is a string as well as `FileId`. Maybe this is important to know...

Does someone have an explanation why this is happening?

Comment: The only reason I can think off are invisible chars in either `UserId` or `FileId`, start teh investigation by a trim() : `where TimeCreated IN (select max(TimeCreated) from table group by trim(FileId), trim(UserId))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use this syntax instead:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by FileId, UserId ORDER BY TimeCreated DESC)rn
  FROM <table>
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This solution is the best working for me. The solution from Zohar Peled is also working, but this one is much faster in my case

Answer (score 2):

What's going wrong is that your inner select returns more than one value. It returns the maximum of `TimeCreated` for each combination `FileId` and `UserID` in the table.

One way to solve it is this:

```
 ...
 FROM table t1
 INNER JOIN 
 (
     select FileId, UserId, max(TimeCreated) as maxTimeCreated
     from table 
     group by FileId, UserId)
 )
 t2 ON t1.TimeCreated = t2.maxTimeCreatedAND t1.UserId = t2.USerId AND T1.FileId = t2.FileId
```

However, if you post your table structure and desired results, someone might show you a better way.

Comment: This solution is working, with a minor adjustment. I needed to add an `AS maxdate` after `max(TimeCreated)` and also use `t1.TimeCreated = maxdate` instead of `t1.TimeCreated = t2.TimeCreated`.

However, in my case this solution is getting quite slow, if it have to return a lot of results. The solution from @t-clausen.dk is way faster in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining the subquery by UserId, so your lower TimeCreated may correspond to another user file.

```
from table t1
where TimeCreated = (select max(TimeCreated) 
                        from table 
                       where table.UserId = t1.UserId 
                         and table.FileId = t1.FileId )
```